# C# Need help working out the average from a txt file using StreamReader

Tags: c#, math

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] hours = new int[30];
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5M;
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00M;
        decimal pay;
        double average;
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("hours.txt");
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            hours[counter] = int.Parse(line);
            counter = counter + 1;
            line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        }
        fileSR.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Hours     Parking Fee");
        for (int i = 0; i < hours.Length; i++)
        {
            pay = Math.Min(hours[i] * HOURLY_RATE, MAX_FEE);
            Console.WriteLine("{0,4} {1,10}", hours[i], pay.ToString("C"));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

As said, I don't have a clue on how to work out the average from a txt file using StreamReader. It would be great if I could have some help. Feel free to edit the code as much as you want to make it work.

At the moment the code outputs into a console application, showing the Hours, and the Parking Fee. But under that I want it to say the average of the Parking Fee.

Comment: Sorry. We don't write code for you here. You need to tell us what your specific problem is, and how it isn't working as you expected. Telling us "feel free to edit the code as much as you want to make it work" is not going to cut it here.

Comment: @krillgar Not asking you to write my code for me. I want an explanation on how I work out the average from a text file when I am using StreamReader.

Comment: If you didn't have to use a stream reader, this is a little simpler: `var average = File.ReadAllLines("hours.txt").Select(int.Parse).Average();`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using StreamReader is irrelevant in this case. What you are doing now is filling an array with the values from the file. These values are stored in `hours` array.

From here, the easiest way would be to take the average from that array:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < hours.Length; i++)
{
    sum += hours[i];
}
double average = sum/hours.Length;
```

or something similar to that, for example with LINQ directly:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

double average = hours.Average();
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I wanted to work out the average of the Parking Fee, what would I have to do. (The parking fee is hours * HOURLY_RATE)

Comment: Since the average is linear, you don't need to calculate the average of the fees, you can calculate directly from the averate (average_fee = average_hours * HOURLY_RATE). If this answer solved your problem, don't forget you can mark it as accepted!